# vb.net RichTextBox Environment.NewLine not showing CR only LF

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

After I run the following in vb.net I am only showing a "LF" and no "CR" (notepad++)

When I copy and paste or open the saved file in notepad it only returns on one line.  Digging deeper I notice there are no CR and only LF.  Any advice on why the CR is not showing up?  The file looks great in RichTextBox.

```
        RichTextReport.AppendText("Printer Report:" + Environment.NewLine)
        RichTextReport.AppendText(sDate + " : " + sTime + Environment.NewLine)
        RichTextReport.AppendText("something")
        RichTextReport.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: Environment.NewLine is OS specific. On which system are you running this code?

Comment: Same development environment.  Windows 7

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce your problem with the code above. Saving the RichTextBox content as PlainText correctly produces the CR/LF sequence as expected on a Windows System

Answer (score -1):

These are the character sequences to create a new line:

- vbCr is the carriage return (return to line beginning),
- vbLf is the line feed (go to next line),
- vbCrLf is the carriage return / line feed (similar to pressing Enter)

You can also call `vbNewLine` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Please replace `Environment.NewLine` with `Convert.ToChar(10)`

Example:

```
RichTextReport.AppendText("Printer Report:" & Convert.ToChar(10))
```